# to show the telephone link in an anchor tag just beside of its phone image and Email link just beside of envelop image

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am trying to show the telephone number link in an anchor tag just beside of its fa fa-phone phone image  and Email link just beside of envelop image. But not working  My code given below,  I want to show the the link to the phone and email should be shown just close and left side to the image

```html
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center text-white">
                        <font color="white">
                            <h4>My Company Ltd</h4>
                        </font>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" text-right>

                        <i class="fa fa-phone" style="color:#fff;"></i> &nbsp;
                        <a href="tel:4324434" style="font-size: 1.5rem; text-decoration: none">32424324</a>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" text-right>

                        <i class="fa fa-envelope" style="color:#fff;"></i> &nbsp;
                        <a href="ppp@gmail.com" style="font-size: 1.3rem; text-decoration: none">ppp@gmail.com</a>


                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add (i) in an anchor tag.

Try this below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center text-white">
         <font color="white">
            <h4>My Company Ltd</h4>
         </font>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" text-right>

         <a href="tel:4324434" style="font-size: 1.5rem; text-decoration: none"><i class="fa fa-phone" style="color:red;"></i> 32424324</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" text-right>

         <a href="ppp@gmail.com" style="font-size: 1.3rem; text-decoration: none"> <i class="fa fa-envelope" style="color:red;"></i> ppp@gmail.com</a>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```